# wpf self-contain application can not run successfully

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I built and published my WPF application as self-contained app. When I run the .exe file in other machine, it is suspended and then killed automatically.

My configuration of .csproj file:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <ApplicationIcon>Images\dspace_icon.ico</ApplicationIcon>
    <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
    <RunPostBuildEvent>OnBuildSuccess</RunPostBuildEvent>     
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I tried both `dotnet build` and `dotnet publish`. Both .exe file do not work.

Comment: Check the logs in *Event Viewer > Windows Logs > Application* on the offending machine.

Comment: Please share the exact problem and your solution for future reference.

Comment: You can first check whether there is an operating environment suitable for running your wpf application on other computers. You can open cmd on the computer that failed to run and run dotnet --info to check whether there is a complete operating environment. In addition, when moving WPF to other computers to run, you need to be careful not to let it lack DLLs and other necessary running elements.